# How to get full url from dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

If I use this:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

I get full url like:

```
http://localhost/mysite/Default.aspx?TabID=269&OTHER-parameters
```

But I don't want this thing with TabID I need friendly url so if I use:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl;
```

I get

```
http://localhost/mysite/something/en-us/generatethings.aspx
```

But with this I don't get parameters :(
How to get full friendly complete url from dnn with all parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to get the current URL within DNN, because the URL gets rewritten before it gets to your module.

What we'll typically do is regenerate the URL, using `Globals.NavigateURL`.  You can use `DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.UrlUtils.GetQSParamsForNavigateURL` to get all of the query string parameters from the current URL.

So, you'd end up with something like this:

```
var currentUrl = Globals.NavigateURL(
    this.TabId, 
    this.Request.QueryString["ctl"], 
    UrlUtils.GetQSParamsForNavigateURL());
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will get you what you want

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
```

Comment: That's going to have the same problem as `Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri`

Comment: That works! Very nice solution to a tricky problem and all in a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
`string url = TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl;`
```

this should give you the user friendly url